# Files Damaged from FTP to R

Tags: r, ftp

I'm trying to download public data from ftp server direct to R, however  I can't open this file because it is damaged.

The code I'm using is the following

```
library(RCurl)
url = "ftp://ftp.mtps.gov.br/pdet/microdados/RAIS/2006/"
filenames = getURL(url, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE)
filenames <- strsplit(filenames, "\r\n")
filenames = unlist(filenames)
for (filename in filenames) {
  download.file(paste(url, filename, sep = ""), paste(getwd(), "/", filename,
                                                      sep = ""))
}
```

Is there any alternative to solve that?

Regards,

Comment: I can't test that URL (it times out for me), but perhaps `getURL(..., binary=TRUE)`? (Has it been slashdotted? ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, r2evans. The URL is only available in Internet Explorer

Comment: No, to me it isn't. I tried with `RCurl::getURL` and `httr::GET`, no luck. I tried in Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Chrome, and they all timed out. (I tried in Edge, but it apparently chooses to not handle the `ftp://` scheme internally, and complains/fails for reasons beyond me.) **However**, I VPNed into Brazil and was able to get to it. So it has nothing to do with the browser, just with the source IP.

Comment: I tried the first (`"AC2006.tz"`, corrupted) and the 28th (`"TO2006.7z"`, corrupted), and couldn't find it. Then I tried the 2nd file (`"AL2006.tz"`) and it is *not* corrupt. It appears that the corruption is in the original files, not necessarily in the download mechanism.

Comment: When I download directly from the ftp server, those files don't seem to be corrupted. For this reason, I thought that the corruption was in the download mechanism

Comment: Try `download.file(..., mode="wb")`. I think I did download the second file directly in my testing, so you are likely correct. The default is `download.file(..., mode="w")`, which is not binary-safe. (If you read `?download.file`, it has a specific note about the use of `"wb"` on windows; not sure if that's relevant to you. Another note from the help: *"On Windows, if 'mode' is not supplied ('missing()') and 'url' ends in one of ..."*, and `.7z` is *not* one of the known endings.)